# Touchbar Sending Virtual Keypresses to Amazon Workspaces

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar, aws

I have a MacBook Pro with the touchbar and I use it to connect to Amazon Workspaces. Workspaces is essentially a Windows VM I connect to for Windows development.

My older MacBook worked great, but Workspaces does not recognize the function keys when I press them on the touchbar. I know this is partly an issue with Workspaces, as virtual keypresses sent via BetterTouchTool [don't work either.](https://community.folivora.ai/t/bettertouchtool-does-not-work-with-amazon-workspaces/1874)

Has anyone had other issues with the "virtual" function keys and found a way to get them to be recognized correctly, by apps that apparently only accept physical keypresses?

Comment: This sounds like an Amazon Workspaces problem - have you contacted them?"

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this problem and found a [workaround](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385276/128088). In the Keyboard settings, set the "Touch bar shows" to "F1, F2, etc. Keys". After this setting, my function keys are being recognized in Amazon WorkSpaces. Although it does not recognize F11 as it still shows desktop on Mac. You also lose firect access to App Controls.

[image]